# Paid Memberships Pro, Display User Limit

Tags: plugins, users

I have this piece of code I'm trying to polish up and set a limit to. Everything seems to work except for the limit part.

Instead of it showing all the profiles, I only want to show 16. The value *2* is there just to make sure its working and only showing 2 profiles.

I've tried a few things, like adding quote marks but it only shows both types of member levels.

Here is the code:

```
//List out all available user based on a passed date, return table
function listAvailable($date = null) {
if ($date == null) {
    $date = Date('m/d/Y');
}
$userList = array();
$str = '';
$args = array(
    'role' => 'team_member',
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'LIMIT' => 2
);
$usr = get_users($args);        
    foreach($usr as $user) {            
        $isAvailable = checkAvailability(userAvailability($user->ID),$date);
        if (get_field('show_all_team',14)) {
            if ($isAvailable || !$isAvailable) {
                array_push($userList,$user->ID);
            }
        } else {
            if ($isAvailable) {
                array_push($userList,$user->ID);
            }
        }
    }   
//$str.=theader(array(''));
//$str.='<tr><td>';
foreach($userList as $user) {
    $details = personDetails($user);
    if (strlen($details['avatar']) > 0) {
        $avatar = $details['avatar'];            
    } else {
        $avatar = '<span class="user-avatar"></span>';
    }
    $str.= '<div class="theuser user-ind-info"><a class="avatar-list" title="'.$details['display_name'].'" href="'.$details['link'].'"><div class="home-username">'. $avatar .$details['display_name'].'</div></a><div class="home-rate-it">'.displayRating($user->ID).'</div></div>';
}
//$str.='</td></tr>';
//$str.=tfooter();
return $str;
}
```

If additional details are needed, please let me know.
This function is used to gather information that is displayed on the homepage.

Comment: Looking at the docs for [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users), `LIMIT` is not a valid argument. It sounds like you need `number`.

Comment: let me give that a shot

Comment: Dude you are the man, if you want to post as an answer ill vote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users), `LIMIT` is not a valid argument. It sounds like you need to use `number` to limit the number of users returned.